# Hyperledger Fabric: IoT use case

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, iot

**Use case**: a smart home which gathers raw data from all the sensors within it, processes them and extracts high level information from them. The owner of the house might want to share these information with other people, such as doctors, family members, friends... So, I'm trying to figure out which would be the best way to handle the access permissions on these data.  Right now all the information are carefully encrypted and stored in a database (untrusted) and only the people with the right keys can properly decrypt those data.

**My idea**: I want to use Hyperledger Fabric to store and manage the access permissions to these files and also to store the hash digest of the gathered information for immutability purposes. Once the smart home generates an high level information from the raw data, it stores it inside the database and then it issues a transaction to Hyperledger Fabric with the timestamp and the hash digest of the data. 
The smart home owner can share these information with other people, issuing a transaction with the ID of this person and an identifier of the data he would have the access rights on. 
So before accessing the information stored inside the encrypted database, the application would check if the requester has the valid permissions stored within the blockchain.

**My doubts and questions**: since I'm really new on this topic, even though I've read a lot about it, I don't know if this would be an improper use of the Hyperledger Fabric. All the use cases I read about it, store all the data with Hyperledger Fabric, without relying on an external cloud storage service.

Since all the transactions would be stored in the blockchain and the blockchain is maintained by all the peers inside the same channel (btw I would use just one channel to keep everything), they may be able to access to the Hyperledger Fabric database and extract information about the smart home. Am I wrong? If not, how can I solve this issue? I could use the identity mixer feature to "hide" the transaction issuer, but still the transaction would be visible to all of the peers who keep the blockchain available.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your questions. We could not hide all information from Peers, but you can encrypt sensitive information and allow specific people to decrypt it as you mentioned. In addition, even you cannot prevent malicious access on time, but you can collect malicious access activities for auditing in the future. for example: using access control on each world state database of peers.